# I can't locate where to fix this error stating "Instance member can't be accessed using static access"

Tags: flutter, dart, instance

I am getting this error

> Instance member can't be accessed using static access

and I can't locate where as I have data related to the error in another class. Am new to Dart Flutter and still learning, so it all isn't making sense to me much.

Code where am getting this error is at `.getLocationWeather()`:

```
 void getLocationData() async {
    var weatherData = await WeatherModel.getLocationWeather();

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return LocationScreen(
        locationWeather: weatherData,
      );
```

Below is the class' code where `getLlocationWeather()` is located.

```
import 'location.dart';
import 'networking.dart';

const apiKey = 'e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713';
const openWeatherMapURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

class WeatherModel {
  Future<dynamic> getCityWeather(String cityName) async {
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        '$openWeatherMapURL?q=$cityName&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        '$openWeatherMapURL?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the brackets around to make it non-static. As following:

```
var weatherData = await WeatherModel().getLocationWeather();
```

Answer (score 0):

To access as static method, you need the make the method as static

```dart
 static Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {
 /// if this function depends on others , those also neeeded to be static as well.
```

Now you can use

```dart
var weatherData = await WeatherModel.getLocationWeather();
```

Or using `WeatherModel().getLocationWeather();` will create a new instance every time you call it.